# SQLite testing if database exits. (Qt)

Tags: qt, sqlite

I have this little code snippet in a Qt application using SQLite:

```
  db.setDatabaseName("./good.db");
  if(!db.open())
    {
      QMessageBox m(QMessageBox::Critical,"Connection Error",db.lastError().text() );
      m.exec();
      exit(0);
    }
```

the problem is that if I replace good.db with a nonexistent file like bad.db then I do not get an error. I guess this makes some sense since I could actually create the database as part of the proccess, ala CREATE TABLE.

I could simply test for the existence of the file, but that seems a vulgar approach to me. Is there any way ( from Qt and libsqlite ) to test for the existence of the database?

Answer (score 0):

With `sqlite3_open` the database is not accessed, and may even be created by a subsequent `sqlite3_` call if it doesn't exist. The `sqlite3_open_v2` has an option `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` that forces an error to be returned if the database does not exist.